# Why is MongoDB changing my UTC time zone from UTC+2:00 to UTC+0 when using Mongoose with moment-timezones.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB changes UTC time from UTC+2:00 to UTC+0.

I tried to add option "{ forceServerObjectId: true }", but didn't helped.

I'm creating date with moment-timezones.js, and basically that's my whole code:

```
        const date = moment().format();
        console.log(date);

        playerDataSchema
          .updateOne(
            { DiscordID: user.id },
            { XPBoost: true, XPBoostExpiration: date }
          )
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store `Date` objects, i.e. use `moment().toDate()`. Storing date values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that.

`Date` values in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - always and only!

Usually the client application takes care that date/time values are displayed in local time zone and format. If you need to preserve the input timezone, then you must store it in a separate field.